# How to control for gender when looking at group differences with a 4-level factor (ANCOVA)?

Tags: r, regression, linear, ancova

So I have a dataset with 4 distinct groups, and I am trying to see if there is a difference between these groups on a dependent variable Y which is cardiorespiratory fitness. I did an ANCOVA and added gender and age as covariates to control for them. In my ouptut, I get:

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
fact_sport    3  13.76   4.586   5.479 0.00137 **
AGE           1   0.14   0.139   0.166 0.68414   
GENDER        1   5.41   5.406   6.459 0.01211 * 
Residuals   142 118.85   0.837
```

So, I have a significant effect of my 4-group factor when controlling for age and gender, as well as an effect of gender.

To observe between which groups lie the differences, I did post-hoc t-tests. The problem is, in my two first group, there is a large gender imbalance (about 80% male in the first group and then 80% female in the second). So when the t-tests is significant between the first and second group on my  dependent variable, I can't be sure that this is not due to the gender imbalance.

I tried doing a linear regression instead, as in the ouptut, we get the detail of each group's relationship with the baseline group, and then changing the baseline group so I get the relationship between each of them. This is one of the outputs:

```
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)     -0.02151    0.65986  -0.033  0.97404   
fact_sportclose -0.17924    0.20565  -0.872  0.38491   
fact_sportmixed -0.23215    0.26146  -0.888  0.37610   
fact_sportnone  -0.78361    0.26979  -2.904  0.00427 **
AGE              0.04435    0.06437   0.689  0.49201   
GENDER          -0.46172    0.18168  -2.541  0.01211 *
```

(The baseline group is fact_sportopen here) So, I guess my question would be, would it be correct to say "**there is a statistically significant difference between the none and the open group when predicting the cardiorespiratory fitness while controlling for age and gender**" ?

And if not, then is there a way to perform t-tests while controlling for gender ? Or can another test do that ? Because the ANCOVA does not give me the details of between which test are the differences.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What I would do: Employ marginal means after the regression with `emmeans`. [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html) is a tutorial from the author of the package.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thank you ! That is really helpful. So that means I can keep my original ANCOVA with the aov function in R, and then employ marginal means, right ?

Comment: `aov` is just a wrapper for `lm` anyways. I don't think it should make any difference. The estimated marginal means should be identical.